# export to csv file from database by passing some constant string variables

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, csv

Let's say my database table structure is like :

```
he     haddress hage   she        saddress     sage
Sam      USA    25   Jenny      germany     21
John     UK     32   Anne       france      29
keith    USA    27   nicole     france      21
```

I want to export this aboce result set into a csv file using this command :

```
select he, haddress, hage, she, saddress, sage into outfile '/tmp/test1.csv' 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n' from table_name;
```

it creates the csv file as following format :

```
Sam,USA,25,Jenny,germany,21
John,UK,32,Anne,france,29
keith,USA,27,nicole,france,21
```

now I want the above as below :

```
Sam,address,USA,age,25,knows,Jenny,address,germany,age,21
.....
.....
.....
```

how to pass these string while generating the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

```
select he, 'address', haddress, 'age',  hage, 'knows', she, 'address', saddress, 'age' sage into outfile '/tmp/test1.csv' 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n' from table_name;
```